# Bitlocker: USB drive accessible by other os users

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, usb-storage

I have a bitlocker encrypted USB drive connected to my PC. I just noticed that other OS-users on that PC can also access the USB drive.

e.g.

- I login to my account - the USB drive is automatically unlocked (I need this for auto-backup on start)
- when I now press WIN+L and switch to another user, that user also has access to the USB drive

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure Bitlocker is a per machine encryption technology, not per user. So as you noticed if one user unlocks a drive, it is unlocked for everybody.

This is also the case for other technologies like VeraCrypt.

You can try to make sure that nobody else can log onto your machine while you have unlocked a drive, and always lock it when you leave.

Otherwise you need to look into other options depending on your needs.